# Js technicue to capture clicks in a shiny app does not capture node id

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, nodes

I have the `shiny` app below in which I use  a js technique to capture clicks in the app without having to use shiny input elements. It works great but not on nodes as I want to be able to capture nodes and get the node ID.

The logic is the following: I click on `"Click me"` text or on the nodes then in Rstudio console I type `input$js.node_clicked`. The result should be "one_1" which I can accept ase `"one"` corresponds to node and "_1" on clicking sequence. But when I click on nodes I get only "_1" and not the node id "one_1". The logic is from [here](http://www.open-meta.org/technology/one-observer-for-all-buttons-in-shiny-using-javascriptjquery/).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(magrittr)

js <- '
$(document).on("click", ".node", function(e) {
if(typeof BUTTON_CLICK_COUNT == "undefined") {
BUTTON_CLICK_COUNT = 1;
} else {
BUTTON_CLICK_COUNT ++;
}
Shiny.onInputChange("js.node_clicked",
e.target.id + "_" + BUTTON_CLICK_COUNT);
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(HTML(js))
  ,
  div(id="one","click me",class="node")
  ,
  uiOutput("main")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$main <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      div(
        grVizOutput("grr", width = "100%", height = "90vh")
      ))
    
  })
  
  output$grr <- renderGrViz(grViz( "digraph test{
A[tooltip='A word'];
B[tooltip='Another word'];
A -> B;}" )
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$js.node_clicked , {
    browser()
  }) #
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: what do you call a "node" ? A child of the document ?

Comment: Ah I didn't see, you defined a class `node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works like this. You have to use `currentTarget` instead of `target`.  Avoid to include a dot in the input name of `Shiny.setInputValue` (or `Shiny.onInputChange`, which is the same), because the dot has a special meaning.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(magrittr)

js <- '
$(document).on("click", ".node", function(e) {
  if(typeof BUTTON_CLICK_COUNT === "undefined") {
    BUTTON_CLICK_COUNT = 1;
  } else {
    BUTTON_CLICK_COUNT++;
  }
  Shiny.setInputValue("js_node_clicked",
    e.currentTarget.id + "_" + BUTTON_CLICK_COUNT);
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(HTML(js)),
  
  div(id="one", "click me", class="node"),
  
  uiOutput("main")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$main <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      div(
        grVizOutput("grr", width = "100%", height = "90vh")
      )
    )
  })
  
  output$grr <- renderGrViz(grViz( "digraph test{
A[tooltip='A word'];
B[tooltip='Another word'];
A -> B;}" )
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$js_node_clicked , {
    print(input$js_node_clicked)
  }) 
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: when I click on one of the 2 nodes I still get only the click sequence _1 and not one_1 or two_1

Comment: @firmo23 Two nodes ? Where is the second one? Am i blind? I see only one div with the `node` class.

Comment: I mean 2 nodes when you run tha app dont you see the circles A and B? When I click inside oen of them I want to get either one_1,one_2,one_3 etc or two_1,two_2,two_3 etc. Now when I click inside the nodes (circles) I get _1,_2,_3 etc

Comment: @firmo23 But your circles don't have the `node` class and they have no id!

Comment: @firmo23 I've just checked with the inspection tool. Indeed, there's an id and there is the class `node`, but this is some SVG so this is special (I don't master svg).

Comment: @firmo23 I edited my answer, I found a solution.

Comment: could you take a look at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71023022/create-a-dynamic-table-on-shiny-app-based-on-shiny-widget-and-row-selection-of-a