# Create a dynamic table on shiny app based on shiny widget and row selection of another datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the shiny app below which initially displays a `checkBoxGroupButtons()` and a table. The table has 5 rows (just example-normally more) if you click on a row then another table is displayed.

The checkbox group has 2 choices  `Elective` and `Non-elective Long Stay`. In this version I have included only calculation for `Elective` using `data[,2]` and `data[,1]` in lines 78-79 of my code. The respective calculations for `Non-elective Long Stay` will be `data[,4]` instead of `data[2,]` and `data[3,]` instead of `data[1,]`.

The initial table is used to give the index or rows selected for the calculation.

So for example if I choose `Elective` and first row I should take a table based on 1st row and with 2 columns in total (only `Elective` as it is now),

If I choose then both `Elective` and `Non-elective Long Stay` another column will be added with the relative calculations.

IF I click on another row lets say row 3 it will be included in the calculations together with row 1 from earlier.

If nothing is chosen the no table is displayed.

To sum up the checkbox sets the service type displayed and the row selection the index of rows that wil be included in the means calculation.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(devtools)

filtercost<-structure(list(Currency = c("A01A1", "A01AG", "A01C1", "A01CG", 
                                        "A03"), `Currency Description` = c("Other Therapist, Adult, One to One", 
                                                                           "Other Therapist, Adult, Group", "Other Therapist, Child, One to One", 
                                                                           "Other Therapist, Child, Group", "Dietitian")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                         -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

datacost<-structure(list(Elective_Activity = c(110, 134, 167, 241, 247), 
                         `Elective_Unit Cost` = c(9329, 5105, 3354, 3116, 2429), `Non-elective Long Stay_Activity` = c(2957, 
                                                                                                                       1899, 2049, 2220, 3388), `Non-elective Long Stay_Unit Cost` = c(6877, 
                                                                                                                                                                                       5455, 3822, 3385, 2533)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "tbl", "data.frame"))
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "National Schedule of NHS Costs")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  
  
  
)

body <- dashboardBody(fluidPage(
           checkboxGroupButtons(
                                     inputId = "somevalue2",
                                     label = "Choose service type:",
                                     choices = c("Elective","Non-elective Long Stay"),
                                     justified = F,
                                     status = "primary",
                                     checkIcon = list(
                                       yes = icon("ok", 
                                                  lib = "glyphicon"),
                                       no = icon("remove",
                                                 lib = "glyphicon"))
                                   ),
                                   box(width = 12,DT::dataTableOutput('selectedrow_costs')),
                                   box(width = 12,DT::dataTableOutput('costs'), height = 150))
                    
           )
    

ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'Search', header, sidebar, body)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

  
  
  output$costs <- DT::renderDataTable({  
    
    dtable <- datatable(
      filtercost, selection = "multiple",rownames=FALSE
    )
    dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency("jqueryui", "1.12.1",
                                     "www/shared/jqueryui",
                                     script = "jquery-ui.min.js",
                                     package = "shiny")
    dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
    dtable
  })
  
  #output$value2 <- renderPrint({ input$somevalue2 })
  
  selectedrow_costsrows <- eventReactive(input$costs_rows_selected, {
    #req(input$costs_rows_selected)
    s <- input$costs_rows_selected
    data <- as.data.frame(datacost[s,])
    names(data) <- NULL 
    data
    
    
    elective_mean<- weighted.mean(as.numeric(data[,2]),as.numeric(data[,1]),na.rm = F)
    elective_se<- sqrt(as.numeric(data[,1])*((as.numeric(data[,2])-elective_mean)^2)/sum(as.numeric(data[,1])))
    elective_CI_l<- elective_mean-1.96*elective_se
    elective_CI_h<- elective_mean+1.96*elective_se
    
    Service_type <- c("Elective")
    Weighted_mean <- round(c(elective_mean),0)
    Weighted_SR <-  round(c(elective_se),0)
    CI_Lower_95 <-  round(c(elective_CI_l),0)
    CI_Upeer_95 <-  round(c(elective_CI_h),0)
    
    
    costtable <- as.data.frame(rbind(Service_type,Weighted_mean,Weighted_SR,CI_Lower_95,CI_Upeer_95))
    costtable
    
    
  })
  
  output$selectedrow_costs <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df=selectedrow_costsrows()})
  

  
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What is missing or deficient here?

Comment: I want to add or remove column to the upper table based on the shiny widget on top and also make the calculations inside the upper table based on the row I choose every time from the table at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will meet your needs.  Please note that you may need to modify the formula for `elective_se` and `elective_se2`.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$costs <- DT::renderDataTable({

    dtable <- datatable(
      filtercost, selection = "multiple",rownames=FALSE
    )
    dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency("jqueryui", "1.12.1",
                                     "www/shared/jqueryui",
                                     script = "jquery-ui.min.js",
                                     package = "shiny")
    dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
    dtable
  })

  #output$value2 <- renderPrint({ input$somevalue2 })

  selectedrow_costsrows <- reactive({ 
    #req(input$costs_rows_selected)
    s <- input$costs_rows_selected
    data <- as.data.frame(datacost[s,])
    names(data) <- NULL
    data
    
    if (is.null(input$costs_rows_selected)) {costtable <- NULL
    }else {
      n <- length(input$costs_rows_selected)
      elective_mean<- weighted.mean(as.numeric(data[,2]),as.numeric(data[,1]),na.rm = F)
      elective_se  <- ifelse(n>1, sqrt(sum((as.numeric(data[,2])-elective_mean)^2)/(n*(n-1))), 0)
      elective_CI_l<- elective_mean-1.96*elective_se
      elective_CI_h<- elective_mean+1.96*elective_se
      
      Service_type <- c("Elective")
      Weighted_mean <- round(c(elective_mean),0)
      Weighted_SR <-  round(c(elective_se),0)
      CI_Lower_95 <-  round(c(elective_CI_l),0)
      CI_Upeer_95 <-  round(c(elective_CI_h),0)

      costtable1 <- as.data.frame(rbind(Service_type,Weighted_mean,Weighted_SR,CI_Lower_95,CI_Upeer_95))
      
      elective_mean2<- weighted.mean(as.numeric(data[,4]),as.numeric(data[,3]),na.rm = F)
      elective_se2  <- ifelse(n>1, sqrt(sum((as.numeric(data[,4])-elective_mean2)^2)/(n*(n-1))), 0)
      elective_CI_l2<- elective_mean2 - 1.96*elective_se2
      elective_CI_h2<- elective_mean2 + 1.96*elective_se2
      
      Service_type2 <- c("Non-elective Long Stay")
      Weighted_mean2 <- round(c(elective_mean2),0)
      Weighted_SR2 <-  round(c(elective_se2),0)
      CI_Lower_952 <-  round(c(elective_CI_l2),0)
      CI_Upeer_952 <-  round(c(elective_CI_h2),0)
      
      costtable2 <- as.data.frame(rbind(Service_type2,Weighted_mean2,Weighted_SR2,CI_Lower_952,CI_Upeer_952))
      colnames(costtable2) <- "V2"
      if (is.null(input$somevalue2)) {costtable <- NULL
      }else if (length(input$somevalue2)==2){
        costtable <- cbind(costtable1,costtable2)
      }else{
        if (input$somevalue2=="Elective"){
          costtable <- costtable1
        }else {
          costtable <- costtable2
        }
      }
    }

    costtable

  })

  output$selectedrow_costs <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df=selectedrow_costsrows()})

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: basically the s <- input$costs_rows_selected stores the index for the selected rows and then data <- as.data.frame(datacost[s,]) subsets the data for these rows and then the calculations happen bellow for wieghted means,sr and CI

Comment: it is close but the most columns that we can have on this table are 2 one for each service type. every time you click on a row you do not add a new column but you update-replace the existing columns V1,V2 or both with the new values

Comment: Please try the updated code.

Comment: thansk a alot that works